Getting the "psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat: missing data for column" error
When trying to load data from a csv file into Postgres db using PostgresHook.bulk_load, an error occurs
[2024-08-20, 09:02:01 UTC] {postgres.py:168} INFO - Running copy expert: COPY test_nikita2 FROM STDIN, filename: /opt/airflow/dags/burmistrov/data_nikita/2024-08-19.csv
[2024-08-20, 09:02:01 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'test_db' for task execution.
[2024-08-20, 09:02:01 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1943} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/decorators/base.py", line 221, in execute
    return_value = super().execute(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 192, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 209, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/burmistrov/test.py", line 175, in transfer_data_api
    hook.bulk_load('test_nikita2', fname)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers/postgres/hooks/postgres.py", line 192, in bulk_load
    self.copy_expert(f"COPY {table} FROM STDIN", tmp_file)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers/postgres/hooks/postgres.py", line 176, in copy_expert
    cur.copy_expert(sql, file)
psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat: missing data for column "impressions"
CONTEXT:  COPY test_nikita2, line 1: "campaign,impressions,clicks,costs"
[2024-08-20, 09:02:01 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1400} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=test_dag, task_id=transfer_data_api, execution_date=20240820T090154, start_date=20240820T090158, end_date=20240820T090201
[2024-08-20, 09:02:01 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:104} ERROR - Failed to execute job 70948 for task transfer_data_api (missing data for column "impressions"
CONTEXT:  COPY test_nikita2, line 1: "campaign,impressions,clicks,costs"
; 58980)
[2024-08-20, 09:02:01 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:228} INFO - Task exited with return code 1

Example of data in csv:
campaign,impressions,clicks,costs
asd.com_xzc_catvendor,52,27,3042.04
sd-fgh.com_SMEG_k50gen,31,1,15.17

The way i create a table:
sql_schema_init = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_nikita2 (
    Campaign text NULL,
    Impressions integer NULL,
    Clicks integer NULL,
    Cost float NULL
);
"""

The way im trying to copy data:
with open(os.path.join(path+"{}.csv".format(get_dates())), 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   f.write(resultcsv)                          
   fname = f.name                
try:
   hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='test_db')
   print(321)
   hook.bulk_load('test_nikita2', fname)                
finally:
   pass

I tried changing the delimiters, doesn't work with either “;” or “,”. I also tried changing the data types in db to just text to get something in there to see where the problem is, but nothing is passed to the table


The issue is missing data for column "impressions" and COPY test_nikita2, line 1: "campaign,impressions,clicks,costs". This "campaign,impressions,clicks,costs" is coming in as a single field that is loading into Campaign and so there is no data for Impressions , Click  and Cost.  Pretty sure the improper formatting is happening in open(). Why are you not using the csv module? Also there is the issue that header is being taken as data. 2) I don't believe your Python code is formatted properly.


To be clearer I am pretty sure f.write(resultcsv) is taking each row of what I presume is a CSV and converting it into a single string e.g campaign,impressions,clicks,costs --> "campaign,impressions,clicks,costs".

PostgresHook's bulk_load function does not support CSV files with headers. Remove the headers (first) line (i.e., "campaign,impressions,clicks,costs") from the CSV file, and you should be OK.

That didn't help, the same error still appears
